# Change woocommerce password protect text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to change the default woocommerce password protext text? Right now it's *This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:*, I would like to change that to something else and include a link.

I was using a password protect plugin that did that but it breaks my site with the newest woocommerce version.

Comment: Please refer this link you need to edit functions.php file for changing. https://wordimpress.com/change-wordpress-default-password-protected-text/

Comment: @RahulS - That code didn't work, but there is a search and replace plugin that I used. Thanks.